# Converting c sequential to OpenMP issues

Tags: c, loops, openmp

I am working on an n-body assignment that converts a sequential program to a parallel one using OpenMP. I have the function below which works fine with OpenMP off but produces an incorrect result otherwise. I have a lock around the only variables updated inside the loop that are not declared within the loop. I have been staring at it for a long time now and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
void update() {
  int i, j;
  Body *tmp;

  omp_lock_t lock;
  omp_init_lock(&lock);

  for (i=0; i<numBodies; i++) {
    double x = bodies[i].x;
    double y = bodies[i].y;
    double vx = bodies[i].vx;
    double vy = bodies[i].vy;
    double ax = 0;
    double ay = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (j=0; j<numBodies; j++) {
      double r, mass, dx, dy, r_squared, acceleration;

      if (j==i) continue;
      dx = bodies[j].x - x;
      dy = bodies[j].y - y;
      mass = bodies[j].mass;
      r_squared = dx*dx + dy*dy;
      if (r_squared != 0) {
        r = sqrt(r_squared);
        if (r != 0) {
          acceleration = K*mass/(r_squared);
          omp_set_lock(&lock);
          ax += acceleration*dx/r;
          ay += acceleration*dy/r;
          omp_unset_lock(&lock);
        }
      }
    }
    x += vx;
    y += vy;
    if (x>=x_max || x<x_min) x=x+(ceil((x_max-x)/univ_x)-1)*univ_x;
    if (y>=y_max || y<y_min) y=y+(ceil((y_max-y)/univ_y)-1)*univ_y;
    vx += ax;
    vy += ay;
    assert(!(isnan(x) || isnan(y)));
    assert(!(isnan(vx) || isnan(vy)));
    bodies_new[i].x = x;
    bodies_new[i].y = y;
    bodies_new[i].vx = vx;
    bodies_new[i].vy = vy;
  }
  tmp = bodies;
  bodies = bodies_new;
  bodies_new = tmp;
  omp_destroy_lock(&lock);
}
```

Comment: Why using locks? Just declare `reduction( +: ax, ay )` instead, that should be much better (although I'm not sure this will fix your issue since I can't see what's wrong beside this right now).

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that shows the error when using OpenMP?

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?  I mean,  how compare incorrect values with those correct?

Comment: How does your serial version look ? does it work ? Also it maybe what you want, but I have to ask are you sure you want to compare a double with equality / inequality ?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by moving the pragma to the outer loop and declaring j and I to be private. Sorry for not being clear in the original post but thank you everyone who took the time to read this and reply.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the pragma to the outer loop, removed the reduction and added I and j as private.